Отправка сообщений с сайта в телеграм от имени пользователя с помощью JS
В интернете нашел способ и разную его реализацию отправки сообщений с сайта с помощью https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage?chat_id=${chatId}. В таком случае в телеграм появляются сообщения от имени бота (как будто бот пишет вам). В этом случае нельзя настроить автоматическое общение с ботом, так как он просто не видит эти сообщения. А как сделать чтобы отправка была от мине пользователя, как буто я зашел в ТГ и отправил сообщение боту. Кто знает, помогите, подскажите.

Непосредственная отправка сообщений ботом через sendMessage бот API — это однонаправленная операция, которая не подразумевает диалог.
Для полноценной интеграции с API Telegram (не Bot API) и отправки сообщений от пользователя к боту, нужно использовать один из многих клиентских API, поддерживаемых Telegram, такой как Telethon (https://docs.telethon.dev/) для Python или TDLib (https://core.telegram.org/tdlib) для разных языков программирования. Такие библиотеки требуют от пользователя аутентификации и подтверждения прав на отправку сообщений.
Использование клиентского API требует защиты частных данных пользователя, включая номер телефона и другую личную информацию. Пользователь должен ясно предоставить свое согласие на такие действия и иметь возможность контролировать, какие сообщения отправляются от его имени.
Другими словами - вы не можете составить так просто такой url-запрос, чтобы отправлять сообщения от имени пользователя. Потому, что предварительно должен быть сделан запрос на авторизацию пользователя и данные этого запроса будут использованы во всех последующих запросах.
Если же прям, ну очень хочется попробовать ручками - можно использовать такие инструменты как Postman или Insomnia. В них можно составлять любые виды запросов, сохранять полученные токены, подставлять их в нужные поля, хидеры и прочее.

Спасибо за подробное пояснение сути вопроса. А если сделать какую нибудь прокладку в виде еще одного бота, который как пользователь будет отправлять умному боту вопросы пользователя с сайта от своего имени?

зачем еще бота? С сайта можно отправлять сообщения от пользователя (есть же веб-версия телеграма). Нужно подключить API к сайту и пройти авторизацию.

Дайте пожалуйста ссылку с примером.

вот же https://web.telegram.org/  А тут инструкция https://vc.ru/u/2637257-anton-romanov/938156-telegram-veb-poshagovaya-instrukciya

А причем тут сайт не пойму? Это обычная вебверсия телеграма. Мне нужно чтобы человек открыл чат на сайте и писал моему телеграм боту от имени пользователя.

нет проблем, вот https://freelance.habr.com/ Любые хотелки за ваши деньги!
